# Views and Filtering Data not getting results

Tags: views

I have created a view to grab all of the invoices in a system, which it does. I have two types of invoices either payable or receivable. I have two filters to start with Published Content = Yes and Content Type = Invoice. I want to be able to filter this on the invoice type so only receivable invoices show up on the view.

I have added another filter that says content type = invoice type but when I do that I get no results at all.

If I leave off the content = invoice type I get all of the invoices. How can I create a filter that will pass the invoice type to the view so I only get the receivable invoice for this particular view.

Comment: Invoice is a entity node? How are you differentiating invoices that are payable and invoices that are receivable? With a field? Or it is a ecommerce site and the entity order has an status of invoice payable or invoice receivable. Either way filter of content type sounds like it is not enough, you need to add a filter of the field differentiating them or a filter of the order status

Comment: Yes the invoice is its own content type and so is invoice type. I'm using an entity reference to bring into the invoice type into the invoice. It's not an ecommerce site. It's more to deal with just a list of invoices for projects. You mention a filter of field, how would I go about doing that? I'm new to Drupal

Answer (score 0):

Create a relationship to the invoice type content type in the view and then add filter for the status field of invoice type taking relation ship when adding the field in the filter.

Relationship can be found under the Advanced section of the view. Pick the suitable Entity Reference for the relationship to invoice type here and add the relationship.

After that if you add the status field to the filter options you have the option to use the relationship for that field.

Comment: I added the relationship to the entity reference Invoice Type I used Referenced I then added a context filter to (Content entity referenced from field_invoice_type) Content: Invoice Type and in the filter criteria I added Content: Invoice Type (= Receivable). I still get no results back from this. I also tried referencing instead of reference and got no results either.

Comment: You should not add a contextual filter, but a regular filter (Filter criteria, where you defined the other filters too).